# Is it a good practice to use Singleton pattern to avoid creation of object multiple times and how it's done

Tags: java, design-patterns

I am using OpenPDF library in my project to create desired PDF. I want to add line separator at different places, so I created a separate method for that and I am calling wherever necessary.

```
private static void addLineSeparator(Document document) {
    LineSeparator separator = new LineSeparator();
    separator.setLineColor(Color.LIGHT_GRAY);
    separator.setLineWidth(2f);
    document.add(new Chunk(separator));
}
```

But the problem is that every time I invoke method, new `LineSeparator()` is created which will be waste of memory.

```java
Document document = new Document();
try {
    PdfWriter.getInstance(document, new FileOutputStream("HelloWorld.pdf"));
    document.open();
    document.add(new Paragraph("Hello World"));
    Paragraph newLine = new Paragraph(Chunk.NEWLINE);
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; ++i) {
        addLineSeparator(document);
        document.add(newLine);
    }
} catch (DocumentException de) {
    System.err.println(de.getMessage());
} catch (IOException ioe) {
    System.err.println(ioe.getMessage());
}
document.close();
```

To get rid of this problem, I created a singleton class for that.

```
public class LineSeparatorSingleton {
    private static LineSeparatorSingleton separatorSingleton;
    private static LineSeparator separator;
    private static Chunk chunk;

    private LineSeparatorSingleton() {
        separator = getLineSeparator();
        chunk = getChunk();
    }

    public static LineSeparatorSingleton getInstance() {
        if (separatorSingleton == null) {
            separatorSingleton = new LineSeparatorSingleton();
        }
        return separatorSingleton;
    }

    public LineSeparator getLineSeparator() {
        if (separator == null) {
            separator = new LineSeparator();
        }
        return separator;
    }

    public Chunk getChunk() {
        if (chunk == null) {
            chunk = new Chunk(getLineSeparator());
        }
        return chunk;
    }

    public void addLineSeparator(Document document) {
        getLineSeparator().setLineColor(Color.LIGHT_GRAY);
        getLineSeparator().setLineWidth(2f);
        document.add(getChunk());
    }
}
```

And using in my main code:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 5; ++i) {
    // addLineSeparator(document);
    LineSeparatorSingleton.getInstance().addLineSeparator(document);
    document.add(newLine);
}
```

Is this the right way to resolve the problem of avoiding the creation of object multiple times? Any suggestions or help would be appreciated.

Comment: You were having resource issues due to an explostion of `LineSeparator`s?

Comment: You wrote: _new `LineSeparator()` is created which will be waste of memory_ How do you know this? Have you monitored the memory usage of your program to verify that this is so?

Comment: Sounds to me like overkill and perhaps even an antipattern for the usecase described. Would personally only utilize a singleton pattern in case I need the same instance due to requirements of the application, not as means for optimization like this. Would be suprised if your example cause memory issues - you are using the language as it is intended and the garbage collector should kick in long before you come even close to any form of problems regarding memory usage.

Comment: @DaveNewton I am not having any resource issue but as per my knowledge, object creation is an expensive operation and if it's done multiple times it's a wastage of memory and time

Comment: @Abra No, I haven't monitored yet, but i just wanted to know what should be the good programming practice for these kind of scenarios

Comment: @cYrixmorten: thank you for pointing out important things. I just wanted to know what should be good programming practice for such cases

Comment: @AkshayaAmar Object creation is relatively cheap, and for something like a PDF, barely matters *(with the caveat that **large** objects, like images/etc, might matter)*. This seems like premature optimization in a problem space that probably doesn't need much, if any, optimization.

Comment: Beside the fact that premature optimization is evil, you may run in problems (probably not with this case) when objects are not thread-safe.

Comment: *it's a wastage of memory and time* - what is the measured contribution to overall memory use and program execution time?  If you haven't measured it, then it's not a problem worth spending time on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would work unless you start playing around with lineColor and lineWidth. However, it’s a bad idea for reasons [mentioned by @cYrixmorten](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76103146/is-it-a-good-practice-to-use-singleton-pattern-to-avoid-creation-of-object-multi#comment134214449_76103146).

A better approach is to make the separator a static constant as follows:

```
private static final LineSeparator SEPARATOR = new LineSeparator() {{
    setLineColor(Color.LIGHT_GRAY);
    setLineWidth(2f);
}};

private static void addLineSeparator(Document document) {  
    document.add(new Chunk(SEPARATOR));
}
```

Comment: Thank you providing me the suggestion John

Comment: Or simpler and more idiomatic and conforming to naming standards: `private static final LineSeparator SEPARATOR = new LineSeparator(){{setLineColor(Color.LIGHT_GRAY); setLineWidth(2f);}};` (of course with proper formatting, which I can't show in a comment).

}

Comment: Agree @Bohemian, I have improved the syntax and used the Java naming convention for a constant.